# creating a table only if it's not existing with ANSI sql

Tags: sql, database, ansi-sql

I am trying to dynamically create a SQL table only if it's not already existing. I have seen many solutions on the internet but they usually rely on a specific database, while I'm trying to find the most generic solution.

I was thinking of always running the CREATE command and then assuming that if it fails then the table exist and I can start inserting data into it. I can't see any flaw in this reasoning (not counting performance issues), but I might be wrong.

Is this an acceptable method?

Can you suggest other methods which are database independent, or that use ANSI SQL that all RDBMS would accept?

Comment: Try-and-fail is probably the safest bet that'd be truly portable. However, it assumes that all databases would produce a failure error condition if the table already exists. I can't think of any DBs offhand that won't, but you never know...

Comment: @Alireza I have to write just a create and an insert query and I don't want to create a whole db class with a lot of cases just to do that.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a table - say - EMP, does that really imply that it is the same EMP that you are expecting?

Either query the appropriate data dictionary for the table structure, or fill your code with a ton of error checking and conditional logic...

Comment: It's just 2 queries so I don't have to check much

Answer (score 0):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is part of the ANSI SQL Standard, so you should be able to:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable')
    CREATE TABLE...
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think Oracle doesn't have one. (It does have catalog tables.) :-)

Comment: @Denis: I believe you're correct, but OP was asking for a solution that used ANSI SQL.

Comment: They edited my question but actually I was just asking for something who works for every major db

Comment: IF doesn't seem to be ANSI.

Answer (score -2):

what about:

```
create table if not exists
```